# Entity Framework why interface class always create on separate file?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

maybe it's a noob question. I tried to google this but can't find the answer.
I'm really wonder, why interface class always create on separate file?
I create my own app using EF. and put the Interface Class under same namespace.
is this against the EF rule design?

```
namespace DSF.Data.Repositories
{
    public interface INewCategoryReponsitory
    {
        IList<NewsCategory> GetAll();
    }

    public class NewCategoryReponsitory : RepositoryBase,INewCategoryReponsitory
    {
        public IList<NewsCategory> GetAll()
        {
            return _db.NewsCategory.ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this against the EF rule design?

Not really, but is does go against interface design.

You want dependencies to depend on the interface, not the implementation.

If you can get intellisense for both, what's stopping you from using the concrete implementation instead of the interface? Nothing, build-wise. Interfaces and implementations are often in either different namespaces or in different assemblies to emphasize their purpose -- dependency decoupling.

Here is where you can use the rules of the C# compiler to coerce programming constraints. You want your implementations to depend on an interface -- that's the whole point of using them, as dependencies. That way no one can sneak in something like `this._repos = new NewCategoryRepository();` and break your unit testability or custom dependency chaining.

If you really want to keep them in the same file, you can try this:

```
namespace DSF.Data.Api
{
    public interface INewCategoryRepository
    {
        IList<NewsCategory> GetAll();
    }
}
namespace DSF.Data.Repositories
{
    using DSF.Data.Api;

    public class NewCategoryRepository : RepositoryBase,INewCategoryRepository
    {
        public IList<NewsCategory> GetAll()
        {
            return _db.NewsCategory.ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

Then in your Controller, only have a using statement for the Api namespace:

```
using DSF.Data.Api;
//using DSF.Data.Repositories; // this makes access to implementation too easy

namespace MvcProj.Controllers
{
    public class NewCategoriesController
    {
        public NewCategoriesController(INewCategoryRepository repos) { ... }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to declare an interface in its own file when you have multiple classes (in different files) implementing it as opposed to your example where it my not matter much. More of an organizational preference than a rule though.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring interfaces in separate files is more a convention than a rule. Indeed, most consider it a good practice to declare only one class/interface per file and to name the file after the class/interface.

This structure helps to organise projects. As it is widely adopted, it makes it easy for different people to read code.